# What are the EXT2 file system structure details?

Tags: filesystems, ext2

I'm trying to wrap my head around the EXT2 file system, but I can't find a single place that shows me the EXT2 file system *in detail*.

I finally drew up a diagram myself.  So I got that far.  Now I'm trying to figure out the following (I've found some info already):

- Number of bytes per sector: 0.5kB - 4kB
- Number of bytes per block: 4kB - 64kB
- Number of sectors per block: 1 - 128
- Number of blocks per block group: ?
- Number of block groups per partition: ?

It's crazy to me that I can't find a single place that has this information.

EDIT: Also just found this, which means my bytes per block number is probably wrong:

```
#define EXT2_MIN_BLOCK_SIZE     1024
#define EXT2_MAX_BLOCK_SIZE     4096
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually find my information about ext2 at the [osdev wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Ext2) which in turn links [here](http://www.nongnu.org/ext2-doc/).

The number of bytes per block is `1024<<n` where `n` is given in the superblock and is a 32 bit integer. So in theory, a block could be anywhere between 1024 and ... lots of bytes. Normally, block sizes of 1, 2, 4 or 8 kB are used, though depending on several factors such as partition size and expected average file size.

Each block group contains a single block bitmap of free blocks. This gives the constraint `8*block size` to the number of blocks per block group. The same is true for inodes per block group. The actual values are found in the superblock.

This in turn gives a lower bound to the number of block groups needed to fill the partition.